# Работа с БД в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Имеется стандартный CRUD редактор, написанный на Spring и Hibernate. Допустим, вызывается метод, создающий объект в базе данных (то есть Create).

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Контрооллер

```
RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    Repository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
        repository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы через 1 минуту **после создания этого объекта** в бд менялся его статус с online на offline. Какие есть способы реализации такой процедуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вручную запускать новый поток, ждать минуту, затем вызывать Hibernate save. Например так:

```
public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
    repository.save(user);
    new Timer().schedule(() -> /* установка status = false */, 60 * 1000);
    return user;
}
```

Но я подозреваю, что вам в будущем придется обновлять статус постоянно, поэтому нужно подумать о том, чтобы это все дело не плодило миллионы потоков. Это уже отдельный вопрос, стоит копать в сторону `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: А если я захочу отменить действие? Например, если за эту минуту пользователь выполнил какое-то действие, то предыдущий поток должен отминиться и должен запуститься новый?

Comment: У TimerTask есть cancel. А вообще еще можно рассмотреть вариант сервиса, который раз в минуту просматривает список активных пользователей и если кто-то уже долго не делал действий, ставим его статус в false. Но я не знаю, будет ли он эффективнее чем существующая реализация Timer, надо смотреть исходный код и возможно проводить бенчмарки. Да и вообще даже если через таймер будете делать, вынести это дело в отдельный сервис будет не лишним - можно будет потом легко заменить реализацию, в случае чего.

Comment: Да, но как программа моймет, что этот Timer Task относится именно к этому id в таблице? Мы ведь не можем сохранить объект TimerTask в список, он является абстрактным. Только записывать id в отдельный список и проверять, не выполняется ли он, так?

Comment: И сможем ли мы снова вызвать тот же TimerTask, если будем хранить id?

Comment: Прошу прощения, мы можем сохранять TimerTask (точнее обьекты классов, наследуемые от него). В таком случае мы можем снова вызвать тот таймер и отменить его. Все работает, спасибо вам за ответ!